# Closed form for an integral involving the incomplete Gamma function?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, gamma-function

Let $\alpha>1$, $K>1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. What is a closed form solution to a tough integral? $$I(\alpha,K,n)=-\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{2 i e^{-i K u} (K u-i) \Bigl[\alpha \, (-i u)^{\alpha } \,\Gamma (-\alpha ,-i u)\Bigr]^n}{u^2} \, du,$$
where $\Gamma(.,.)$ is the incomplete Gamma function:
$\Gamma (a,z)=\int _z^{\infty }d t\, t^{a-1} e^{-t}$.

I tried all manner of substitutions and various combinations of integration by parts.

Comment: By parts failed, tried substitution, no result.

Comment: @Nero Why don't you just say that in OP?

Comment: Dear close voters, do you even [know who Nero is](https://twitter.com/nntaleb/status/681299339856211968)?

Comment: Not that I expect to be able to do the integral, but to confirm - is the 2-variable $\Gamma$ function above the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function?

Comment: @DaviH, think as a principal value integral.

Comment: @Nero Ok, we're on the same page now regarding principal value (I was thinking of another usage of the term earlier). With that settled, I think the clear strategy here is to use the integral representation for the incomplete gamma function to express your integral as an $n+1$-fold multiple integral, and then change the order of integration and integrate over $u$ first. As a side note, it would be convenient here if we could impose the condition $K\le n$. The integral can be solved without this condition, but it would eliminate some casework if it were true.

Comment: @David H yes, actually $K \leq n$. Working on the double integral.

Comment: @David, yes it is the convolution of 2 Fourier Transforms, one for a Pareto distribution (n-summed), the other a Heaviside above K giving Sign[x-K]. Can explain in the OP or in the solution if I finf it.

Comment: NNT/Nero, now that you haven't gotten responses or further details on maths se, why don't you go to maths overflow, stats se or operations research se?

Answer (score 11):

We may use the following integral representation for the incomplete gamma function ([DLMF ref. see identity 8.6.4](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6)):

> $$\Gamma{\left(\alpha,z\right)}=\frac{z^{\alpha}e^{-z}}{\Gamma{\left(1-\alpha\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{-\alpha}e^{-t}}{z+t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left|\arg{\left(z\right)}\right|<\pi,~\Re{\left(\alpha\right)}<1}.$$

---

Given $n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\land a,b,\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}\land1<a\land1\le b\le n\land0<\epsilon$, define $I_{n}{\left(a,b;\epsilon\right)}$ via the integral

$$I_{n}{\left(a,b;\epsilon\right)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2ie^{-ibx}\left(bx-i\right)\left[a\left(-ix\right)^{a}\,\Gamma{\left(-a,-ix\right)}\right]^{n}}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}.$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
I_{n}{\left(a,b;\epsilon\right)}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2ie^{-ibx}\left(bx-i\right)\left[a\left(-ix\right)^{a}\,\Gamma{\left(-a,-ix\right)}\right]^{n}}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2ie^{-ibx}\left(bx-i\right)}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\left[\frac{e^{ix}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}e^{-t}}{t-ix}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]^{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2ie^{-ibx}\left(bx-i\right)}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}e^{inx}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}e^{-t}}{t-ix}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]^{n}\\
&=\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(bx-i\right)e^{i\left(n-b\right)x}}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}e^{-t}}{t-ix}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]^{n}\\
&=\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(bx-i\right)e^{i\left(n-b\right)x}}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t_{k}\,\frac{t_{k}^{a}e^{-t_{k}}}{t_{k}-ix}\\
&=\small{\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(bx-i\right)e^{i\left(n-b\right)x}}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,e^{-\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{t_{k}^{a}}{t_{k}-ix}\right)}\\
&=\small{\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}^{a}\right)e^{-\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(bx-i\right)e^{i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\left(x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}-ix\right)}}\\
&=\small{\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}^{a}\right)}{\exp{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\right)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(-bx-i\right)e^{-i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\left(x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}+ix\right)}}\\
&=:\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}^{a}\right)}{\exp{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\right)}}\,f_{n}{\left(b;\epsilon\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where for $n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}\land b,\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}\land1\le b\le n\land0<\epsilon$ we've defined the auxiliary function denoting the innermost integration,

$$f_{n}{\left(b;\epsilon\right)}:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(-bx-i\right)e^{-i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\left(x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}+ix\right)}.$$

For the integration over $x$, I will appeal to a well-suited proposition from Gradshteyn's *Tables*. Now, I usually try to make my posts as self-contained as possible by proving any non-trivial lemmas I plan on using, rather than taking the lazy way out and simply citing the result from an outside source. But I can't resist doing so, partly out of laziness, but mostly just to show off how Gradshteyn can on occasion be eerily clairvoyant.

> **Gradshteyn 3.386:** Given the conditions
>   $$-1<\Re{\left(\nu_{0}\right)}\land0<\Re{\left(\beta_{k}\right)}\land\sum_{k=0}^{n}\Re{\left(\nu_{k}\right)}<1\land0<p,$$
>   we have the following two results:
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\left(ix\right)^{\nu_{0}}e^{-ipx}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\beta_{k}+ix\right)^{\nu_{k}}}{\beta_{0}-ix}\mathrm{d}x=2\pi e^{-\beta_{0}p}\beta_{0}^{\nu_{0}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\beta_{0}+\beta_{k}\right)^{\nu_{k}},$$
>   and
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\left(ix\right)^{\nu_{0}}e^{-ipx}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\beta_{k}+ix\right)^{\nu_{k}}}{\beta_{0}+ix}\mathrm{d}x=0.$$

---

The following partial fraction decomposition is easily verified:

$$\frac{-bx-i}{x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}=\frac{1}{2i\epsilon}\left[\frac{\left(1-b\epsilon\right)}{\epsilon-ix}+\frac{\left(1+b\epsilon\right)}{\epsilon+ix}\right].$$

Then, assuming $0<\Re{\left(t_{k}\right)}\land b<n$,

$$\begin{align}
f_{n}{\left(b;\epsilon\right)}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(-bx-i\right)e^{-i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\left(x^{2}+\epsilon^{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}+ix\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{2i\epsilon}\left[\frac{\left(1-b\epsilon\right)}{\epsilon-ix}+\frac{\left(1+b\epsilon\right)}{\epsilon+ix}\right]\frac{e^{-i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}+ix\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-b\epsilon}{2i\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{e^{-i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\left(\epsilon-ix\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}+ix\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1+b\epsilon}{2i\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{e^{-i\left(n-b\right)x}}{\left(\epsilon+ix\right)\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(t_{k}+ix\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-b\epsilon}{2i\epsilon}\cdot\frac{2\pi e^{-\left(n-b\right)\epsilon}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\epsilon+t_{k}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
I_{n}{\left(a,b;\epsilon\right)}
&=\frac{2i}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}^{a}\right)}{\exp{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\right)}}\,f_{n}{\left(b;\epsilon\right)}\\
&=\frac{2\pi\left(1-b\epsilon\right)e^{-\left(n-b\right)\epsilon}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}\epsilon}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,\frac{\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}^{a}\right)}{\exp{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}\right)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\epsilon+t_{k}\right)}\\
&=\frac{2\pi\left(1-b\epsilon\right)e^{-\left(n-b\right)\epsilon}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}\epsilon}\int_{[0,\infty)^{n}}\mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{t}\,\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{t_{k}^{a}e^{-t_{k}}}{\epsilon+t_{k}}\right)\\
&=\frac{2\pi\left(1-b\epsilon\right)e^{-\left(n-b\right)\epsilon}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}\epsilon}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(\frac{t^{a}e^{-t}}{\epsilon+t}\right)\right]^{n}\\
&=\frac{2\pi\left(1-b\epsilon\right)e^{-\left(n-b\right)\epsilon}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(a\right)}\right]^{n}\epsilon}\left[\epsilon^{a}e^{\epsilon}\,\Gamma{\left(1+a\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(-a,\epsilon\right)}\right]^{n}\\
&=2\pi a^{n}\left(1-b\epsilon\right)\epsilon^{na-1}e^{b\epsilon}\left[\Gamma{\left(-a,\epsilon\right)}\right]^{n}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: (+1) The integral stated in Gradshteyn can actually be computed fairly quickly by considering a semicircle in the LHP indented around $z=0$. Since this contour also avoids the other branch points at $z=ia_k$ , and the integral along the big arc and the indentaions have vanishing contributions due to Jordan's Lemma and $-1<\Re(a)$ respectively,
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{(ix)^a e^{-ibx}\prod^n_{k=1}(a_k+ix)^{b_k}}{a_0-ix}\ dx=\color{red}{-}2\pi i\times\frac{(i(-ia_0))^a e^{-i(-ia_0)b}\prod^n_{k=1}(a_k+i(-ia_0))^{b_k}}{-i}$$
The other integral is $0$ since the integrand is analytic in the LHP.

Comment: Hi, what if b is not lower than n? They are just both >1. Actually I am considering $ K=n \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: David H any response to @Nero ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer, linked with the calculations via multiple convolution.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Representation of the integral.}}$

Is known that

- $$s^p\Gamma(-p,s) = E_{p+1}(s),$$
- $$\dfrac1{2\pi i} \int\limits_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}F(s)\,e^{ts}\,\text ds 
  = \mathcal L^{-1}_{s\mapsto t}(F(s)),$$
- $$\mathcal L^{-1}_{s\mapsto t}(e^{s} E_{p+1}(s)) = \dfrac1{(t+1)^{p+1}},$$

where $\;E_{p+1}(s)\;$ is the exponential integral $\;E\;$ and $\;\mathcal L^{-1}_{s\mapsto t}\;$ is the inverse Laplace transform from $\;s\;$ to $\;t.$

Let $\;-iu =s,\quad K=n+t,\;$ then
$$I(\alpha,n+t,n) = \dfrac{4\pi}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}\dfrac{(n+t)s-1}{s^2}\big(\alpha s^\alpha\Gamma(-\alpha, s)\big)^ne^{(n+t)s}\text ds$$
$$ = \dfrac{4\pi\alpha^n}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{-i\infty}^{+i\infty}\dfrac{(n+t)s-1}{s^2}\big(e^s\,E_{\alpha+1}(s)\big)^n\,e^{ts}\,\text ds
=4\pi\alpha^n\mathcal L^{-1}_{s\,\mapsto t}\left(\dfrac{(n+t)s-1}{s^2}\big(e^s\,E_{\alpha+1}(s)\big)^n\right),$$
$$=4\pi\alpha^n\left((n+t)\int\limits_0^t G_n(\alpha,\lambda)\,\text d\lambda
-\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^\lambda G_n(\alpha,\mu)\,\text d\mu\,\text d\lambda \right)$$
$$=4\pi\alpha^n\left((n+t)\int\limits_0^t G_n(\alpha,\lambda)\,\text d\lambda
-\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^\lambda G_n(\alpha,\mu)\,\text d\mu\,\text d(n+\lambda) \right)$$
$$\;\overset{\text{IBP}}{=\!=}\; 4\pi\alpha^n \int\limits_0^t(n+\lambda)G_n(\alpha,\lambda)\,\text d\lambda,$$
$$I(\alpha,n+t,n)=4\pi\alpha^n\int\limits_0^t(n+\lambda)
G_n(\alpha,\lambda)\,\text d\lambda,\tag1$$
where
$$G_n(\alpha,t) = \underbrace{\dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha+1}}*\dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha+1}}*\dots*\dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha+1}}}_n\tag2$$
is the multiple convolution.

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Case\; n = 1.}}$

\begin{cases}
G_1(\alpha,t)=\dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha+1}}\\
\big(G_1(\alpha,t)\big)'_t = -\dfrac1{(\alpha+1)(t+1)^{\alpha+2}}\\
\int\limits_0^t G_1(\alpha,t)\,\text dt
=\dfrac1\alpha \left(1 - \dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha}}\right).\tag3
\end{cases}
$$I(\alpha,t+1,1) = 4\pi\alpha\int\limits_0^t \dfrac{\text d\lambda} {(\lambda+1)^{\alpha}} 
= \dfrac{4\pi\alpha}{\alpha-1}\left(1-\dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha-1}}\right),$$
$$I(\alpha,K,1) = \dfrac{4\pi\alpha}{\alpha-1}\left(1-\dfrac1{K^{\alpha-1}}\right).\tag4$$

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Case\; n = 2.}}$

$$G_2(\alpha,t) = G_1(\alpha,t) * \dfrac1{(t+1)^{\alpha+1}}
=\int\limits_0^t G_1(\alpha,u)\,\dfrac{\text du}{(t-u+1)^{\alpha+1}},\tag5$$

$$I(\alpha,t+2,2) = 4\pi\alpha^2\int\limits_0^t \int\limits_0^\lambda \dfrac{(\lambda+2) G_1(\alpha,\mu)}{(\lambda-\mu+1)^{\alpha+1}}\,\text d\mu\,\text d\lambda$$
$$= 4\pi\alpha^2\int\limits_0^t \int\limits_0^\mu \dfrac{\big((\lambda-\mu+1) + (\mu+1)\big) G_1(\alpha,\mu)}{(\lambda-\mu+1)^{\alpha+1}}\,\text d\lambda\,\text d\mu$$
$$= 4\pi\alpha^2\int\limits_0^t \int\limits_0^\mu \left(
\dfrac{G_1(\alpha,\mu)}{(\lambda-\mu+1)^{\alpha}} 
+\dfrac{G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)}{(\lambda-\mu+1)^{\alpha+1}} 
\right)\,\text d\lambda\,\text d\mu$$
$$= -4\pi\alpha^2\int\limits_0^t \left(
\dfrac{G_1(\alpha,\mu)}{(\alpha-1)(\lambda-\mu+1)^{\alpha-1}} 
+\dfrac{G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)}{\alpha(\lambda-\mu+1)^{\alpha}} 
\right)\bigg|_0^\mu\,\text d\mu$$
$$= \dfrac{4\pi\alpha}{\alpha-1}\int\limits_0^t
\big(\alpha G_1(\alpha,\mu)(1-G_1(\alpha-2,-\mu))
+(\alpha-1)G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)(1-G_1(\alpha-1,-\mu))\big)
\,\text d\mu$$
$$= \dfrac{4\pi\alpha}{\alpha-1}\int\limits_0^t
(1-G_1(\alpha-2,-\mu))\,\text d G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)$$
$$- 4\pi\alpha \int\limits_0^t G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)(1-G_1(\alpha-1,-\mu)))
\,\text d\mu$$
$$= \dfrac{4\pi\alpha}{\alpha-1}
(1-G_1(\alpha-2,-\mu))\,G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)\bigg|_0^t
- 4\pi\alpha\int\limits_0^t G_1(\alpha-1,\mu) G_1(\alpha-1,-\mu) \,\text d\mu$$
$$- 4\pi\alpha (1-G_1(\alpha-2,-t)))
+ 4\pi\alpha \int\limits_0^t G_1(\alpha-1,\mu)G_1(\alpha-1,-\mu)\,\text d\mu$$
$$= \dfrac{4\pi}{\alpha-1}(1-G_1(\alpha-2,-t))\big(\alpha G_1(\alpha-1,t)
- \alpha+1)\big),$$

$$I(\alpha,K,2) = \dfrac{4\pi}{\alpha-1}(1-G_1(\alpha-2,K-2))\big(\alpha G_1(\alpha-1,K-2)
- \alpha+1)\big),\tag6$$

$$G_2(\alpha,t)=\int\limits_0^t\dfrac{\text du}{(u+1)^{\alpha+1}(t-u+1)^{\alpha+1}}
=\int\limits_1^{t+1}\dfrac{\text du}{u^{\alpha+1}(t+2-u)^{\alpha+1}}\\[4pt]
=\dfrac1{(t+2)^{2\alpha+1}}\int\limits_1^{t+1}\dfrac{\text d\left(\frac u{t+2}\right)}{\left(\frac u{t+2}\right)^{\alpha+1}\left(1-\frac u{t+2}\right)^{\alpha+1}} 
=\dfrac1{(t+2)^{2\alpha+1}}\int\limits_{\large\frac1{t+2}}^{\large\frac{t+1}{t+2}} s^{-\alpha-1}(1-s)^{-\alpha-1}\text ds,$$
$$G_2(\alpha,t) = \dfrac{\text B_{\large\frac{t+1}{t+2}}(-\alpha,-\alpha)
-\text B_{\large\frac1{t+2}}(-\alpha,-\alpha)}{(t+2)^{2\alpha+1}}.\tag7$$

Obtained results show that algebraic closed form of the given integral can exist even if the convolution has not such form.

However, I have not any closed forms for $n\ge3.$